# Message box with an error message

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following message box and code:

```
'Message box to ensure that the accounting format equals the loan withdrawl country
    If txtloanwithcountry = "England" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Wales" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Scotland" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Norther-Ireland" Then
    NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

    Else

    MsgBox "The currency used in the loan withdrawl country must be equal to number format"

    End If
```

However, I want to show it as an error, so it does not show up in the worksheet. Do anyone know the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
'Message box to ensure that the accounting format equals the loan withdrawl country
If txtloanwithcountry = "England" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Wales" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Scotland" Or txtloanwithcountry = "Norther-Ireland" Then
NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

Else

MsgBox "The currency used in the loan withdrawl country must be equal to number format", vbCritical

End If
```

Comment: Is it possible to then make sure that the values that I have inputted in the user form do not show in the worksheet?

Comment: @Gjovis You're going to need to add more to your original question - you never mentioned a userform, we don't know how you get those values - most likely you're going to want to prevent your user from entering those values to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Assuming the txtloanwithcountry string is in cells(2,2) on the activesheet
'Assuming the cell to be formatted is cells(2,4) on the activesheet
'Edit: I am changing the cell's font color to white if there is an error in
'      the Country to hide the Error Message so it does not show up

Sub FormatCurrency()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim rng as Range
Dim txtloandwithcountry as String

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set rng = ws.Cells(2,2)

With rng

    .offset(0, 2).Value = ""
    .offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "General"
    .offset(0, 2).Font.Color = vbBlack

    txtloanwithcountry = .Value

    Select Case txtloanwithcountry

        Case "England", "Wales", "Scotland", "Northern-Ireland"

            .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "_(£* #,##0.00_);_(£* (#,##0.00);_(£* ""-""??_);_(@_)"

        Case Else

            .Offset(0, 2).Value = "ERROR"
            .Offset(0, 2).Font.Color = vbWhite

    End Select

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how/where you set `NumberFormat` (and associated values), this is one of those situations where `Variant` is useful.

If this is in a UDF - make the return type `Variant` and you can return `CVErr(xlErrValue)`. The `CVErr` is important because it tells the variant that it is an error type, not just an enumeration.

If you are inputing directly into a cell, you can use the same variant value.

In both cases it will show up as `#Value!` in the sheet.